# Implementing Longest Common Substring using Suffix Array

Tags: c++, arrays, suffix-array, longest-substring, longest-prefix

I am using [this program](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/4025) for computing the suffix array and the Longest Common Prefix.

I am required to calculate the longest common substring between two strings.

For that, I concatenate strings, `A#B` and then use [this algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9555/computing-the-longest-common-substring-of-two-strings-using-suffix-arrays).

I have Suffix Array `sa[]` and the `LCP[]` array.

The the longest common substring is the max value of `LCP[]` array.

In order to find the substring, the only condition is that among substrings of common lengths, the one occurring the first time in string B should be the answer.

For that, I maintain max of the LCP[]. If `LCP[curr_index] == max`, then I make sure that the `left_index` of the substring B is smaller than the previous value of `left_index`.

However, this approach is not giving a right answer. Where is the fault?

```
max=-1;
for(int i=1;i<strlen(S)-1;++i)
{
    //checking that sa[i+1] occurs after s[i] or not
    if(lcp[i] >= max && sa[i] < l1 && sa[i+1] >= l1+1 )
    {
        if( max == lcp[i] && sa[i+1] < left_index ) left_index=sa[i+1];

        else if (lcp[i] > ma )
        {
            left_index=sa[i+1];
            max=lcp[i];
        }
    }
    //checking that sa[i+1] occurs after s[i] or not
    else if (lcp[i] >= max && sa[i] >= l1+1 && sa[i+1] < l1 )
    {
        if( max == lcp[i] && sa[i] < left_index) left_index=sa[i];

        else if (lcp[i]>ma)
        {
            left_index=sa[i];
            max=lcp[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, This problem is from a programming contest and discussing about programming problems of ongoing contest before editorials have been released shouldn't be .... Although I am giving you some insights as I got **Wrong Answer** with suffix array. Then I used **suffix Automaton** which gives me Accepted.

Suffix array works in `O(nlog^2 n)` whereas Suffix Automaton works in `O(n)`. So my advice is go with suffix Automaton and you will surely get Accepted.
And if you can code [solution for that problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/LCS/), you will surely code this.

Also found in codchef forum that:

```
Try this case 
babaazzzzyy 
badyybac 
The suffix array will contain baa... (From 1st string ) , baba.. ( from first string ) , bac ( from second string ) , bad from second string .
So if you are examining consecutive entries of SA then you will find a match at "baba" and "bac" and find the index of "ba" as 7 in second string , even though its actually at index 1 also . 
Its likely that you may output "yy" instead of "ba"
```

And also handling the constraint ***...the first longest common substring to be found on the second string, should be written to output...*** would be very easy in case of suffix automaton. Best of luck!